# Where am I going wrong with downsampling this data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes.

One lists 30-minute observations of particular values (`actual` and `forecast`) over a 24-hour period (48 observations):

```
> api_df.head()

                from                 to  actual  forecast     index
0  2019-11-24T23:30Z  2019-11-25T00:00Z     200       210  moderate
1  2019-11-25T00:00Z  2019-11-25T00:30Z     200       199  moderate
2  2019-11-25T00:30Z  2019-11-25T01:00Z     198       200  moderate
3  2019-11-25T01:00Z  2019-11-25T01:30Z     189       204  moderate
4  2019-11-25T01:30Z  2019-11-25T02:00Z     191       199  moderate
```

The other is observations of another value (`KW`) over an entire day:

```
> csv_extr.head()

            Date              Time          KW
3764  2019-11-25  13:45:26.1050000 -424.437988
2911  2019-11-25  16:41:12.4040000 -465.325989
1786  2019-11-25  13:06:54.0290000 -431.795013
4352  2019-11-25  18:42:19.9360000 -452.528992
4634  2019-11-25  19:35:19.9230000 -457.210999
```

I want to get `csv_extr` to resemble `api_df` as closely as possbile, so I decided to downsample it and I ended up with something that is *almost* what (I think) I'm looking for, but there are some clear issues, namely the `Time` value and `NaN` observations:

```
> x.head()

         Date              Time     KW  time
0  2019-11-25  00:00:01.6470000 -100.0     0
1         NaN               NaN    NaN     0
2         NaN               NaN    NaN     1
3  2019-11-25  01:57:04.7700000    0.0     0
4         NaN               NaN    NaN     2
```

I have looked for possible reasons why, and I can only assume that these results are occurring because `Time` is set to seven decimal places and thus causes the output to not be neatly aligned to 30-minute blocks for some reason.

I achieve this final output (`x`) using some code that I found online, but I cannot find an explanation as to what precisely the code is doing and would like some guidance here also:

```
t = pd.to_timedelta(csv_extr.Time, unit = "min")
s = csv_extr.set_index(t).resample('30min').last().reset_index(drop = True)
x = s.assign(time = s.groupby("Time").cumcount())
```

There is a single error notification that appears when this code segment runs which is:

```
ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed
```

As before, I have looked for what this might mean but haven't yet found anything that clearly explains it.

I am happy to provide data for reprex purposes; the reason I haven't provided anything (yet) is because I am unclear of the best way to do this in Python/pandas (some guidance here would be good).  Also, I am hoping that the solution is a case of a more experienced Python user than myself looking at the code and spotting something obvious.  Otherwise I am happy to provide the data required for a reprex.

Comment: have you tried rounding the time in `csv_extr` to the nearest 30mins and then merging the dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You converted "Time" to a timedelta, but it looks like a timestamp to me, so I think you want `pd.to_datetime`, which is what I did to get the following approximation to your data.  And I also set the index to the new "DateTime" column and drop the old columns:

```
csv_extr['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(csv_extr.Date + ' ' + csv_extr.Time)

csv_extr = csv_extr[['KW','DateTime']].set_index('DateTime')

                                 KW
DateTime                           
2019-11-25 13:45:26.105 -424.437988
2019-11-25 16:41:12.404 -465.325989
2019-11-25 13:06:54.029 -431.795013
2019-11-25 18:42:19.936 -452.528992
2019-11-25 19:35:19.923 -457.210999
```

It's pretty straightforward after that.  I'll show 60 minute resampling here to keep the output more compact, but it works just the same for 30 minute sampling, of course:

```
csv_extr.resample('60 min').last()

                             KW
DateTime                       
2019-11-25 13:00:00 -424.437988
2019-11-25 14:00:00         NaN
2019-11-25 15:00:00         NaN
2019-11-25 16:00:00 -465.325989
2019-11-25 17:00:00         NaN
2019-11-25 18:00:00 -452.528992
2019-11-25 19:00:00 -457.210999
```

I assume you want to fill in the missing values there.  Without knowing more about your data, I'd suggest a simple linear interpolation like the following (but pandas and numpy have plenty of other options if you want something more complicated):

```
csv_extr.resample('60 min').last().interpolate()

                             KW
DateTime                       
2019-11-25 13:00:00 -424.437988
2019-11-25 14:00:00 -438.067322
2019-11-25 15:00:00 -451.696655
2019-11-25 16:00:00 -465.325989
2019-11-25 17:00:00 -458.927490
2019-11-25 18:00:00 -452.528992
2019-11-25 19:00:00 -457.210999
```

Comment: Thank you; this is just what I was looking for. In terms of interpolation, can you provide me with any guidance around the other available options?

Comment: @Mus It's hard to say, not knowing your specific situation.  Just look at the documentation on interpolation -- default is linear but it has many other methods available.  Note you could also replace `last()` with `mean()`, among other things.  Again, just depends on your situation.